# Calling javascript function from component AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I'm new to Angular's component and am trying to create header/footer for my website.

This is my current header component that I declared in the same file as my controller.

```
app.component('headerComponent', {

    template: '<div class="header"><div class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5"><!-- Logo --><div class="logo"><h1><a 
    href="adminHome.html">'+ localStorage.getItem('username')+'</a></h1>
    </div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-
    12"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><div class="navbar navbar-
    inverse" role="banner"><nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-
    collapse navbar-right" role="navigation"><ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li 
    class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-
    toggle="dropdown">My Account <b class="caret"></b></a><ul 
    class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInUp"><li><a 
    href="profile.html">Profile</a></li><li><a href ng-
    click="logout();">Logout</a></li></ul></li></ul></nav></div></div></div>
    </div></div>',

});
```

when i try to use the header component tags to include my header, my logout function does not work. How do I use a function that is declared outside of this component? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just being in the same file will not be enough. When you define the component, you need to tell angularJs what controller to use, or it will use a default controller (which is basically an empty function). Additionally, components use controller-as syntax, so you can't just call `logout()`, you need to call `$ctrl.logout()`. So for example:

```
// I did the controller as a constructor function, but you could also do a class
const MyController = function ($log) {
   this.logout = function () {
      $log.info('you clicked the logout button!);
   }
}

app.component('headerComponent', {
    template: '<a ng-click="$ctrl.logout()">hello world</a>,
    controller: MyController
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working now after adding the controller. Also, if it is possible to use a function that is not declared in the controller? One that exist in a html script tags